# Quadratic solution theorem

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

In "How To Prove It", Ch 3.1 exercise 2 Vellman writes:

***Theorem*** *Suppose* $b^2 > 4ac$. *Then the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has exactly two  real distinct solutions.*

Vellman then asks: To give an instance of this theorem, we replace $a,b,c$ but not $x$. Why ?

Answers online pointed that $a,b,c$ are free variables but $x$ is a bounded one.

Now what confuses me here is that $a,b,c$ in this context are arbitrary constants not free variables also if we restate the theorem as

***Theorem*** *For every real numbers $a,b $ and $ c$, if $b^2>4ac$  the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has exactly two real distinct solutions.*

Then $a,b,c$ become bound variables while it is still the exact same theorem.

What exactly is $x$. Is it free, bound or neither ? ***"CONTINUATION"***

Also the theorem can be stated as:

***Theorem*** Let $a,b$ and $c$ be real numbers and $b^2>4ac$. There exists exactly two  real distinct numbers $h_1$ and $h_2$ such that the $ah_1^2 +bh_1+c=0$ and $ah_2^2 +bh_2+c=0$.

In the last restatement $x$ was completely removed.

What exactly is $x$ and does this sort of variable occur in other theorems?

The part after continuation apparently wasn't posted at first.

Comment: You should replace $ac$ by $4ac$ throughout.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers $a,b$, and $c$ determine whether we have an instance of the theorem, namely whether the *assumption* of the theorem, $b^2>4ac$, is satisfied. Once we replace those three by specific numbers, we either have an instance ie. $b^2>4ac$ or not ie. $b^2\leq 4ac$. So different values $a,b$, and $c$ produce different instances.

On the other hand, $x$ plays no role in the *assumptions* of the theorem, but in the *implications* of it.

Note also that we distinguish between $x$ as being the independent variable in the expression $ax^2+bx+c$, or the unknown of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, or $x$ taking on *specific values* in order to either satisfy or not satisfy this equation. The fact that $x=h_1$ and $x=h_2$ satisfies $ax^2+bx+c=0$ does not mean that $x$ is no longer a variable. It only means that when $x$ assumes these two specific values, it will make the statement $ax^2+bx+c=0$ true. For all other values of $x$ the statement will be false. So let us not confuse the variable $x$ with specific values of it $h_1,h_2$. A variable and its values are different concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your theorem as
$$\forall a,b,c,~b^2 > a c~\Rightarrow \mathrm{Card}\{x~|~ax^2 +bx+c=0\}=2$$

It starts with $\forall a,b,c$, so you can instantiate $a,b,c$ to instantiate your theorem. While there is no $\forall x$, so you cannot "choose" $x$.

Answer (score 1):

"Free", "arbitrary" and "constant", in mathspeak, are merely figures of speech.  All Mathematics can be written without every using them.  For example, the first theorem can be rewritten as:

Suppose three real numbers, $a$, $b$ and $c$, satisfy $b^2>ac$, then there are two different real numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $ax_i^2+bx_i+c=0$ for both $i=1,2$.

(The second is wrong, unless you look for solutions in the complex field and you count multiplicities, but you probably want to think about this later.)

Comment: What "second" ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the second "theorem" in the question post.

Comment: Does $b^2 > ac$ guarantee exactly two solutions? How about $x^2+2x+1$? I guess it should be $b^2 > 4ac$ or in general $b^2 \neq 4ac$

Comment: real solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Updated it.

Comment: "Guarantee" in English means to ensure, i.e., "sufficient" in logic.  Not necessary.  Example, "A marriage with the wrong person guarantees unhappiness." doesn't say that if you marry the right person you'll be happy :-)

Comment: @Nameless the pedant (me) would also replace "exactly two" with "exactly two distinct real" (some people like to think of a solution with multiplicity two as *two* indistinct solutions, as in $(x-1)^2=0$).