# Checking an answer from How To Prove It

Tags: logic, quadratics, predicate-logic

I am not sure whether my answer to the following question is correct or not. The question is,

> **Theorem.** *Suppose that $b^2 \gt 4ac$. Then the quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ has exactly two real solutions.*
>
> To give an instance of the theorem, you must specify values for $a$, $b$ and $c$, but not $x$. Why?

I found some answers online but they used math I haven't seen [yet](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1440754/629938). My answer is,

The sentence *'the quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ has exactly two solutions'* transcribed to logic is,

$\exists x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R (ax_1^2 + bx_1 + c = 0 \ \land \ ax_2^2 + bx_2 + c = 0 \ \land \ \forall y((y \neq x_1 \lor y \neq x_2) \rightarrow ay^2 + by + c \neq 0) $

You do not need to give a value for $x$ because it doesn't occur freely.

Is this right? And also is the transcription right?

Comment: You need to say $x_1\neq x_2$.

Comment: I have trouble understanding why you are trying to use formal logic to answer the question "*Why?*. Why can't you just explain that the value of $x$ is irrelevant in $b^2>4ac$?

Comment: Also I think that you should use the conjuntion instead of the disjunction in the scope of the universal quantifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the theorem says :

> for every $a,b,c$ (real numbers) the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has exactly two real solutions iff $b^2 > 4ac$.

Thus, an *instance* of the above equation will be obtained instantiating the leading universal quantifiers with three individual real numbers, says : $a=1, b=3, c=2$.

The result will be the individual equation :

> $x^2+3x+2=0$

whose roots are : $-1,-2$.

The roots must not be "specified" because they must be computed from the individual equation.

---

In fully symbolic form the theorem will be :

> $\forall a,b,c \ \exists x_1,x_2 [x_1 \ne x_2 \land \ldots \land \forall z (az^2+bz+c=0 \to z=x_1 \lor z=x_2)]$.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost correct. You forgot to add that $x_1\neq x_2$.